# Vuex is resetting already set states

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router, state-management

Have started to play around with Vuex and am a bit confused.

It triggers the action `GET_RECRUITERS` everytime I load the component `company.vue` thus also making an api-call.

For example if I open `company.vue` => navigate to the `user/edit.vue` with `vue-router` and them go back it will call the action/api again (The recruiters are saved in the store accordinly to Vue-dev-tools).

Please correct me if I'm wrong - It should not trigger the action/api and thus resetting the state if I go back to the page again, correct? Or have I missunderstood the intent of Vuex?

**company.vue**

```
<template>
  <card>

    <select>
      <option v-for="recruiter in recruiters"
              :value="recruiter.id">
        {{ recruiter.name }}
      </option>
    </select>

  </card>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default {
  middleware: 'auth',

  mounted() {
    this.$store.dispatch("company/GET_RECRUITERS")
  },

  computed: mapGetters({
    recruiters: 'company/recruiters'
  }),

}
</script>
```

**company.js**

```
import axios from 'axios'

// state
export const state = {
  recruiters: [],
}

// getters
export const getters = {
  recruiters: state => { 
    return state.recruiters
  }
}

// actions
export const actions = {
  GET_RECRUITERS(context) {

    axios.get("api/recruiters")
      .then((response) => {
        console.log('API Action GET_RECRUITERS')
        context.commit("GET_RECRUITERS", response.data.data) 
      })
      .catch(() => { console.log("Error........") })
  }

}

// mutations
export const mutations = {
  GET_RECRUITERS(state, data) {
    return state.recruiters = data
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You have the request inside the `mounted` hook so it will get called every time the component is mounted. Try it in the `created` hook instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's expected behavior, because a page component is created/mounted again each time you route back to it unless you cache it.  Here are a few design patterns for this:

- Load the data in *App.vue* which only runs once.
- Or, check that the data isn't already loaded before making the API call:

```js
// Testing that your `recruiters` getter has no length before loading data
mounted() {
   if(!this.recruiters.length) {
      this.$store.dispatch("company/GET_RECRUITERS");
   }
}
```

- Or, cache the page component so it's not recreated each time you route away and back.  Do this by using the `<keep-alive>` component to wrap the `<router-view>`:

```html
<keep-alive>
   <router-view :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>
</keep-alive>
```